# Get original HTTP response of a WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm calling a SOAP web service using WCF. When the server gots error or turns into maintenance state, it replies with a HTML document. With WCF client an `TargetInvocationException` will be thrown because the reply is not a soap message.

I want to intercept the HTTP response and do some process (logging for exemple) when the server turns into abnormal state. I tried the `IClientMessageInspector` with `IEndpointBehavior`, when the server replies well (even Soap Fault), the method `IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply` fires and i can catch the message.

But when the server replies with a HTML document (where i need that method fired), that method did not fired. i just got `TargetInvocationException` and within that exception i can not get the original http reponse.

Does any one faced the same problem and maybe a solution for this ?
Thanks.